# R Function Within Nested For Loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am applying a custom function over all combinations from two data sets.  Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

```
ptm <- proc.time()
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  d <- list()
  for (j in 1:nrow(centroids)) {
    d[j] <- f_dist(x[i,],centroids[j,])
  }
  x[i,]$cluster <- which.min(d) 
  x[i,]$dist_from_centroid <- d[which.min(d)]
}
proc.time()-ptm
```

Comment: Please provide the code for user defined function

Comment: Probably? Give a sample of your data, a more detailed question, a desired output, what you've tried and then we may be able to help you out. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: Tip#1 Preallocate `d`, i.e. instead of `d <- list()` do something like `d <-rep(list(NA),nrow(centroids)`

Comment: Are you trying to conduct K-means or some similar clustering heuristic?  If this is not a pedagogical exercise then you are much better using Base R functions or a clustering packages.  This approach will be much faster because they will likely interface with C/C++.